# cannot convert image to byte array

Tags: java

I am trying to convert an image stored in a folder in localhost for ex :

```
String imagePath = "http://localhost:8080/ABCD/profile_203.jpg"
```

to byte array, but i am getting this exception "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!".
 When i give path of an image from some other location its getting converted to byte array.

```
String imagePath = "C:\\Users\\Vallabh.Lakade\\Desktop\\profilepic\\profile_203.jpg";
```

is working.This is my code.

```
try{
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", baos);
    baos.flush();
    byte[] imageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    alertParams.put("imageInBytes", imageInBytes);

    return new BaseVO(alertParams, Constants.STATUS_OK, Constants.STATUS_OK_MSG);
    }
catch(Exception e){
    return new BaseVO(alertParams, Constants.STATUS_ERROR, Constants.STATUS_ERROR_MSG);
}
```

Comment: Are you deployed a webapp on localhost:8080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is not file. Try to use URL instead

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new URL(imagePath));
```